# Create Postgres Event Trigger in AWS-RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need an *event* trigger on my RDS Postgres database. Ultimately, I need to be notified whenever there is a change to the schema. In plain old Postgres (i.e. a non-RDS instance) this works fine. However, in RDS running the following:

`CREATE EVENT TRIGGER audit ON ddl_command_start EXECUTE PROCEDURE stat_audit();`

Results in:

```
ERROR:  permission denied to create event trigger
HINT:  Must be superuser to create an event trigger.
```

As far as I understand the most privileged role on RDS is rds_superuser.  I have granted rds_superuser to my account (e.g. `grant rds_superuser to someuser;` ).  Yet I still cannot create the event trigger. I do understand that the rds_superuser is not the same exact role as the pg superuser (which can be confirmed by either running:`SHOW is_superuser` or `SELECT * FROM pg_user`).
I also understand why RDS might lock-down true superuser privileges, but it seems a pretty significant limitation if I cannot access event triggers. Am I missing something? Is is possible to set an event trigger in Postgres on RDS? If not, is there any alternative to mimic the same functionality? I am aware of RDS Event Notifications, but there does not seem to be any option to subscribe to schema change events.

Comment: same problem here :/ have you found any solution?

Comment: @arod my research in community (including amazon) found no options. While I have no found anything concretely saying this is not possible in RDS. It does seem you need to a pg super user to set pg event triggers. In RDS this is not possible (only rds_superuser).  I was forced to go another route.

Comment: what route did you take?

Comment: @arod in my case, since I was interested in dispatching a message on schema changes, I was able to piggy-back on migrations and publish to rabbitMQ. Not ideal, but it more or less works for my needs. I, however, obviously miss mods that might be made outside of migrations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question but this seems to be supported now.

> PostgreSQL versions 9.4.9 and later and version 9.5.4 and later
>   support event triggers, and Amazon RDS supports event triggers for
>   these versions. The master user account can be used to create, modify,
>   rename, and delete event triggers. Event triggers are at the DB
>   instance level, so they can apply to all databases on an instance. For
>   more information about PostgreSQL event triggers on Amazon RDS, see
>   Event Triggers for PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.EventTriggers

Comment: The link is gone from AWS website but archive.org has it: https://web.archive.org/web/20190404104732/https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.EventTriggers